# How to sum the duplicate values?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a MySQL table with rows containing duplicate values of `text` (`'a'` and `'c'`):

```
+------+-----+
| text | num |
+------+-----+
| a    |  10 |
| b    |  10 |
| c    |  10 |
| d    |  10 |
| c    |   5 |
| z    |  10 |
| a    |   6 |
+------+-----+
```

So, I want to update these rows summing the values of `num`. After that the table should look like this:

```
+------+-----+
| text | num |
+------+-----+
| a    |  16 |
| b    |  10 |
| c    |  15 |
| d    |  10 |
| z    |  10 |
+------+-----+
```

UPD: Edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a temporary table to store the aggregated data temporarily into that and then update the original table from it.

1. Create a temporary table
2. select the aggregated data from the original
3. then delete all data in the original table
4. and then select the aggregated data from the temporary table into the original table.

Example SQL:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table_name_tmp` LIKE `table_name`;
INSERT INTO `table_name_tmp` SELECT `text`, SUM(num) AS num FROM `table_name` GROUP BY 1;
DELETE FROM `table_name`;
INSERT INTO `table_name` SELECT * FROM `table_name_tmp`;
-- COMMIT;
```

I commented out the `COMMIT` command to avoid unwanted errors, please check the results before using it.

Comment: It works fine. But, can I do the same thing without copying the whole table? If the table is big it would take much time.

Comment: @AndrewShulgin Sorry I don't really know any better solution.

Comment: Ok, if i'll find any better solution i'll tell you. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use the aggregate function `SUM` with a `GROUP BY` clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT `text`, SUM(num) AS num
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY `text`;
```

### [SQL fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/586f6/2)

This will give you:

```
| TEXT | NUM |
--------------
|    a |  16 |
|    b |  10 |
|    c |  15 |
|    d |  10 |
|    z |  10 |
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I make according changes in the table?

Comment: @AndrewShulgin - What do you mean? This query will work fine after any change in the table.

Comment: I mean that I want to make changes to the table (change the `num` on the first 'a' row and remove all following 'a' rows).

Comment: @AndrewShulgin Yes it should work fine, whatever changes you make to the table values.

Comment: No. I mean that I want to know how to update the first `a` row in the table and delete all other `a` rows. In other words, I want to save output of your SELECT command to the table.

Comment: @AndrewShulgin - You didn't say that in your question, please update your question and explain clearly what are you trying to do.

Comment: Done. Sorry for that. It's my first question on Stack Overflow.